# How to create a query condition to bring all names that start with J

Tags: sql

My Code, I just dont know how set the condition for name to bring names that start with J

```
        SELECT Name, CellPhone
        FROM Employee 
        WHERE ExperienceLevel = “Master”
        AND Name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Name, CellPhone
        FROM Employee 
        WHERE ExperienceLevel = “Master”
        AND Name like 'J%'
```